# Older science fiction, where renowned, only world news service is corrupt (Like Google doing Bad)

Tags: story-identification, teleportation

I read a VERY detailed book about the usual good guy with no abilities who stumbles upon 'bad dealings in high places'. In this case, it's the far future where the ONLY reliable thing in the whole world after all the bad that humans have put themselves through is that the blank blank news service gives live and background factual information. (Kind of like how Google is the 'Do No Harm' company).

The main protagonist is a freelance report selling stories to the news service. He gets cut off from being able to sell stories after he tries to sell a particular one, gets the police after him, etc). Along the way, he meets a girl who can teleport herself through the phone lines (obviously written before ANY kind of portable phone.) It's pretty darn eerie the similarities between Google's influence on the world of information (in western society) and this news service, which ended up being corrupt and changing the news to make money.

Would love to read it again, but cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: How old is "older"? Older than what?

Comment: Oooh, this is ringing bells. Probably published in the late 70's, 80's or early 90's.

Comment: If the 'bad dealings in high places' is the act of making immortality serum out of the children of the poor, then it's most likely "Bug Jack Barron" by Norman Spinrad, the most famous banned SF book in England.

Comment: A world where the news is corrupt? So, this world shortly before Fox News premieres, then. [MRC.org](http://www.mrc.org)